# React router 6 never unmount component when URL parameter changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

We have a problem with the react router v6. When the URL parameters change, it is already using the mount component. Never unmount and mount the component.

Produced code example - if switching between link 1 and link 2(url parameter (id) changes), the Link component never unmount and mount:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-agqlf5-gohmbu?file=src/routes/link.jsx

So how do we get it to be unmount and mount component when the url parameter changes?

Comment: Are you talking about the App component not being unmounted?

Comment: No. The Link component never unmount and mount when url parameter (id) changes.

Comment: So you dont want the link component to be there all the time,  you wanna get back to the home page which doesn't render the link component ?

Comment: if you click link 1 , the link component mount. Then if click link 2 the link component no unmount and mount just using old mounted link component.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is by-design. If you look at the `Route` rendering the `Invoices` component

```
<Route path="link/:id" element={<Invoices />} />
```

There is nothing here to cause (a) the `Route` to remount, and (b) the routed component `Invoices` to remount. If the route path updates it will only trigger a rerender of the routed component, only values in the routing context have changed really. Think of this more like an update to props triggering a component to rerender, not remount.

If the routed component needs to "listen" to and respond to route param changes then it should use a `useEffect` hook to issue any side-effects.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Invoices() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mount');
    return () => console.log('unmount');
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Route parameter changed", { id });
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', paddingTop: '1rem' }}>
      <nav>Invoice ID: {id}</nav>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you ***really*** want to remount the routed component then create a wrapper component that reads the `id` route path param and sets a React key on the routed component. The `InvoicesWrapper` will remain mounted but when the `id` route param updates the `Invoices` component will remount since it has a new React key.

Example:

```
const InvoicesWrapper = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return <Invoices key={id} />
};
```

...

```
...
<Route path="link/:id" element={<InvoicesWrapper />} />
...
```

Comment: You saved hours of googling !!!!!

Comment: i really did want to remount, as i was using a library that was relying on the component lifecycle to create/destroy components and it was hanging on to stale data. your answer helped me big time :)